# Transformation of Lasso to quadratic linear constrained form

Tags: optimization, regression, regularization

The Lagrange formulation of the Lasso problem has the following form:
$$\min_x ||Ax-b||_{2}^2+\lambda||x||_1$$
In the [OSQP paper](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/osqp.pdf)(A.5) by Stellato et al. there is the quadratic version
$$\min_{x,t} y^\intercal y + \lambda \textbf{1}^\intercal t \\s.t. \ Ax-b=y, -t \leq x \leq t$$
where $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The paper says, these two formulations are equivalent. I see how we transform the first summand, but how follows this for the second summand? Intuitively I would say that the second summand in the quadratic version is more related to the $\ell_\infty $-norm than to the $\ell_1$-norm.

Comment: You're missing a transpose in the quadratic program.

Comment: $t$ is same length of $x$, so the inequality really means $t_i\geq |x_i|$, and in the objective you should add the $t_i$'s up.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks for your answer. But why can I sum up the $t_i$'s instead of the $|x_i |$'s?

Comment: In the optimal solution $t_i$ will be equal $|x_i|$, otherwise you could decrease them and have a feasible point with smaller objective. It is a case of the statement that minimizing $f(x)$ is the same as minimizing a new variable $t$ subject to $t\geq f(x)$. In this case you use this transformation to fit your problem in QP form.

Answer (score 0):

The second summand is related to the $\ell_1$-norm because in each pair $-t_i \leq x_i \leq t_i$ one and exactly one inequality is tight. (By contradiction: if neither inequality is tight, we can decrease $\lambda \boldsymbol{1}^T t$ without violating any constraint.) See also the following note for more details and further pointers: [Lasso regularization in quadratic programming](https://scaron.info/blog/lasso-regularization-in-quadratic-programming.html).